# Google Play - Icon not valid

Tags: java, android, xml, icons, google-play

I get this error that my icon is not valid.. The thing is that it's the same icon as in the previous version, I just renamed it and now it doesn't work any more.. Even if I name it back like it was before..

[image]

Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ml.dannyb.packagetracker"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name=".activities.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.PackageDetails" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.BarcodeScannerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />


        <service android:name=".workers.ServiceBackgroundChecker" />


        <receiver
            android:name=".workers.BroadcastReceiverStartBackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="ml.dannyb.packageTracker.SERVICE_START" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".workers.BroadcastReceiverBoot"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Just a thought, do you think it has something to do with Google assuming you are breaching Copyright on your own product logo?

Comment: @Ankush how could someone ever break copyright on their own product?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml Robots aren't perfect, and like I said it was just a thought, the "bot" may have found an image in it's database and not have linked it with the developer.

Comment: Found the answer.. It was jpeg vs png and not a Copyright thing.. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ohh.. How lame.. I had the image as a png and as a jpeg and I thought I need a special image for Lollipop+ notifications so I edited the png so I was left out with only the jpeg and there came the error.. After I converted jpeg to png everything works perfectly.. No Copyright issues :)